# Create UIManagedDocument or equivalent on Mac OS / Cocoa

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa, core-data, uimanageddocument

I would like to create the equivalent of `UIManagedDocument` on Mac OS X (Cocoa) and use this file on iOS. 
How can this be done?
Can we expect to get a `UIManagedDocument` class or equivalent on Mac OS X soon?

Comment: @David Caunt, I believe having heard from Apple that they plan to bring the equivalent of UIManagedDocument to the Mac. Unfortunately I don't remember the source. Do you have heard the same?

Comment: I haven't seen anything I'm afraid. The linked [GitHub repo](https://github.com/karelia/BSManagedDocument) looks promising though.